# Python Pandas DataFrame: combining columns in order providing average values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, average

I have a dataframe as below. I want to combine 4 columns in order and have new df with average of it's values. Please see for detail.

```
a = np.random.randint(5, size=(2, 24))
df = pd.DataFrame(a,index=['alpha','bravo'])    

df:
        0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
alpha   3   0   0   4   4   0   2   2   0   4   2   0   3   4   3   4   3   2   2   3   4   0   0   0
bravo   4   4   4   4   5   2   2   1   4   2   4   0   1   4   3   2   2   3   1   0   3   1   0   0
```

ideal output is below

```
df_new:
        0   4   8   12  16  20 
alpha   3.5 2   3   3.5 2.5 1   
bravo   4   2.5 2.5 2.5 1.5 1
```

So bottom line is that I am combining 4 columns each (in order) and giving average of its values. Is there a pythonic way to do this instead of writing '+' signs of every columns? My actual df is much larger, so I wish there is some other way. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, column names is going to be renamed, so it does not have to be in order of 0,4,8,12,16,20 as long as they are combined in order. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need floor divide array created by `np.arange` with groupby and aggregate `mean`:

```
a = np.arange(0, len(df.columns)) // 4 * 4
print (a)
[ 0  0  0  0  4  4  4  4  8  8  8  8 12 12 12 12 16 16 16 16 20 20 20 20]

df = df.groupby(a, axis=1).mean()
print (df)
         0    4    8    12   16   20
alpha  1.75  2.0  1.5  3.5  2.5  1.0
bravo  4.00  2.5  2.5  2.5  1.5  1.0
```

Comment: wow that simple? Can you please explain what //4 means?

Comment: It is floor dividing columns names by `4`